# Custom sorting based on location and rating in Elasticsearch

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, location

We are currently building a "best" approach for our record listing where we have a demand to sort records based on geo-distance and rating together.

For example, records which are from distance 0-1Km will be sorted based on the higher rating and records from 1-2km will be sorted on the higher rating too. But any record which has geo-distance 0.95 Km and a rating of 7, Another record which has geo-distance 1.1Km and a rating of 9. The record with 0.95Km Distance will come on top. So, distances are grouped in 1Km distance and then they are sorted based on the rating.

How can I apply this directly on elasticsearch. I guess custom sorting script will be required for it?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

Sort all of your results by 'rating':

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html

apply a geo distance agg:

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-geodistance-aggregation.html

Within the geo agg, embed a top hits agg to see the actual results:

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html

If this does't result in the top hits in each geo range bucket being sorted by 'rating', then make the query a function score query with the score just being the rating.

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html